# Toggle clicked row only, with checkboxes using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello would someone help me out here?

I am trying to to do the following :

```
<table>
<thead> 
    <tr> 
        <th>Select</th> 
        <th>Name</th> 
    </tr>
</thead>    
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
    </td>
    <td>
        Sam, Walls
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="show">
    <td colspan="2">
        This is the info about Sam.
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
    </td>
    <td>
        John, Doe
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="show">
    <td colspan="2">
        This is the info about John.
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

When the checkbox with class="toggle" is clicked I only want the row below it to appear.

My JavaScript code that does not work so well is as follows:

```
$('.show').hide();
$('.toggle').click(function(){
    $('.show').slideToggle();
});
```

Currently it will only hide and toggle the Sam, Walls row.

**EDIT : After using class instead of ID the hide issue seems to have been solved. Now however when I click one check box, both rows are toggled together. I updated the code above.**

Any help would be appreciated!

Cheers.

Comment: You can't have two items with the same ID.  Change it to a class `.toggle'

Comment: well that solved the hide issue. Now however both rows are toggled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mentioned in a comment that you cannot have duplicate id's, and that also goes for your `#show` element.  Use the `next` function instead so whatever item you press, the next element will toggle.  Something like:

```
$('.show').hide();
$('.toggle').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').next().slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: should be $(this).closest('tr').next().slideToggle(); and this fixed it, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use your classes and toggle using the index of the one clicked...

```
$('.show').hide();
$('.toggle').click(function(){
    $('.show').eq($('.toggle').index(this)).slideToggle();
});
```